# How does kinetic energy do work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

To my understanding, work is done on object A when object B is applying a force on object A, causing object A to displace.

Since energy is the ability to do work, what work does a moving object do, due to its kinetic energy? I mean, if I kick a ball, it has kinetic energy due to its velocity, but what force does it apply? On what object?

Comment: I think I have a deep misconception on this subject, so I would be grateful to a good explanation, yet not too advanced one (mathematically speaking).

Comment: An object in motion will stay in motion unless a force is applied. When the ball hits something, then it will apply a force. Just moving, it doesn't (well, neglecting air resistance).

Comment: It is a good answer, so I think you should write it as one so I could accept it. But a follow-up question: If for example the ball hits a building, then there is no work because there is no displacement. So actually the kinetic energy did not did work. What is the explanation? Thank a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is - you say *"energy is the **ability** to do work"* and then you are wondering what work is done by an object with kinetic energy, but having the *ability* to do something is not the same as doing something.

Comment: @ACuriousMind - First, I think the title edit is not good because I want to do how the kinetic energy becomes work, end not how kinetic energy works... Secondly - I understand that now after reading Jon Custer's answer. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Um, the title edit is because that way it is proper English. But I realize know that you wanted to ask something slightly different, I'll edit it again.

Comment: @ACuriousMind - Thanks! My English is not so good... Anyway, could you please answer the question I asked Jon Custer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To my understanding, work is done on object A when object B is
>   applying a force on object A, causing object A to displace.

Work is done whenever a force displaces an object.

> Since energy is the ability to do work, what work does a moving object
>   do, due to its kinetic energy?

A moving object might not do any work at all. Imagine an empty universe with just a ball. The ball is moving, meaning it possesses some kinetic energy. If nothing interferes, (and we're on an hypothetical empty universe, so there's nothing to interfere), the ball will just keep moving indeterminately.

> I mean, if I kick a ball, it has kinetic energy due to its velocity,
>   but what force does it apply? On what object?

If you kick a ball you're transferring energy to the ball. The ball that was quiet and had zero kinetic energy, now has some kinetic energy, proportional to the square of its velocity.

If you ignore air resistance, it won't be applying force on anything/any object. However, if we consider that the ball is near enough of the Earth, the ball will have a force applied on it: gravity force, in the direction of the center of the Earth. (actually, the ball itself will also be applying a force on Earth, but given the magnitude of the difference between their masses, let's ignore this). And this force from the Earth will be changing the speed of the ball, thus changing its kinetic energy, (transforming it in potential energy in case the ball is going up, and actually providing it with more kinetic energy in case the ball is going down).

If you don't ignore air resistance, the ball will be pushing and displacing the air particles. Meaning it is applying a force and displacing them, thus doing work on them.

So to answer your question, just because an object *has* kinetic energy, does not mean it is using it. If there is no change of state, there's no "usage".

I sincerely hope my answer helps you understand it better :)

Comment: It did answer my question. Thanks! But if it hits a wall, the ball will not move, so there is no work done in here... So what is happening here? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

From what I understand of your question, you mean to ask what is the work if when you hit the ball, the ball is against a wall and doesn't move? If that's the case, there's no change of state, there's no work done.  And in that case we're talking about Newtown's third law. You might want to do that as a new question ;)

Comment: I think I understand the answer from your comment. Tell me if I am right, please. When the ball hits the wall, it cannot do any force that will displace the wall, so instead it will transform to another kind of energy, which could also do that work? I am sorry for my English... :\

Answer (score 0):

The work the ball that you kick does is the ball going against air-resistance and changing its velocity.

Comment: At least to me that seems very reasonable

Comment: But what if there is nor air resistance, like in space? Where can we see the work then? Thanks a lot.

Comment: In space the work done is the change in velocity. It takes energy to speed up things for example a rocket even if there is no air-resistance.

Comment: But work is to displace an object using force, not changing its velocity...

Comment: You are displacing the object by making your foot be in the place that the ball was in by doing this you are increasing its velocity.

Comment: Ok, but after I kicked, the ball still has a kinetic energy, which means that it has the ability to do work. But what work can it do, for example, if it hits a building?

Comment: If it hits a building the work it does is turning kinetic energy into sound energy, heat energy... and it even passes on some of its kinetic energy to the house even though you don't see the house move.

Comment: It does somewhat answer my question but I cannot upvote the answer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Alright I hope I helped :)

Comment: I think it's because I do not have enough reputation.